# Unity C# tcpclient stream.Read StartCoroutine Problem

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

I am developing TcpClient with Unity3D.

There's a problem.

```
                    if (length == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BATTLE_CHARACTER_DATA_GROUP_SEND))+1)
                    {

                            BATTLE_CHARACTER_DATA_GROUP_SEND bcdgs = new BATTLE_CHARACTER_DATA_GROUP_SEND();
                            bcdgs.Deserialize(ref bytes);
                            Debug.Log("bcdgs data Size : " + bcdgs.data_size);
                            StartCoroutine(PlayerObjectCreate(bcdgs));
                    }
```

If you try to create an object of mainThread in the code above, but you run StartCoroutine, it will send "0" client disconnect value to Server side.

What's wrong with my code?

Below are some full sources.

please.

```
        private void ConnectToTcpServer()
{
    try
    {
        clientReceiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForData));
        clientReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        clientReceiveThread.Start();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("On Client Connect Exception " + e);
    }
}
private void ListenForData()
{
    try
    {
        socketConnection = new TcpClient("192.168.235.128", 53390);
        if (socketConnection.Connected)
        {
            ServerConnected = true;
            Debug.Log("Connected!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            ServerConnected = false;
            Debug.Log("Not Connected!!!");
        }

        while (true)
        {

            using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream())
            {
                int length;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BATTLE_CHARACTER_DATA_GROUP_SEND))+1];
                while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {                        
                    Debug.Log("length : " + length);
                    if (length == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BATTLE_CHARACTER_DATA_GROUP_SEND))+1)
                    {

                            BATTLE_CHARACTER_DATA_GROUP_SEND bcdgs = new BATTLE_CHARACTER_DATA_GROUP_SEND();
                            bcdgs.Deserialize(ref bytes);
                            Debug.Log("bcdgs data Size : " + bcdgs.data_size);

StartCoroutine(PlayerObjectCreate(bcdgs));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        Debug.Log("Socket Exception : " + socketException.ToString());            
    }
}
```

Comment: We did not use the dispatcher and put it in List. In Corutine, we made object when List Counter is> 0.

Comment: Could you also add the content of `PlayerObjectCreate`?

Comment: yes PlayerObjectCreate Corutine